# ¿Por qué me aparece texto html comentado adicional en la respuesta vía ajax desde el server? "<!-- licencia de encabezado... -->"

Tags: php, netbeans

estoy haciendo una petición asíncrona AJAX desde JavaScript usando la librería JQuery "$.ajax({...});" apuntando debidamente a la URL de mi función PHP la cual procesa debidamente la peticion (GET O POST), he procesado la respuesta de esa petición en formato JSON inclusive y sin problemas hasta ahí; Sucede que cuando inspecciono dicha respuesta a través de la herramienta para desarrolladores de Chrome y poniendo un punto de depuración en la respuesta "success: function(){...}"
me llega un texto muy incomodo comentado en html con la siguiente información:

```
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
```

despues de ese texto, aparece mi respuesta, la que realmente espero sin problema alguno. Cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando NetBeans 8.1 y segun lo que he consultado se debe a que hay que cambiar la licencia de encabezado - license header, pero no consigo eliminar dicho error. Lo raro es que abro un proyecto que hice antes de éste, en NetBeans y no aparece dicho mensaje en las respuestas. Lo ideal seria NO tener que crear el proyecto desde cero y pasar artefacto por artefacto (*.PHP, *.CSS, *.JS, ETC). Agradezco de corazón a quien tenga buen olfato de lo que pasa o sepa con exactitud que es lo que sucede en realidad.[image: Mensaje del servidor visto desde la herramienta para desarrolladores CHROME]

[image: codigo desde JavaScript de una sencilla petición AJAX **sin errores de sintaxis**]

Comment: el texto html comentado "<!--  --> " contiene ésta información :  To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties. To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates and open the template in the editor.

Comment: no intentaste seguir la recomendacion del mensaje y cambiar la licencia ? si usas alguna tool como ser PostMan o Fiddler para invocar la url con POST, obtienes el misma respuesta?

Comment: Hola Leandro! si intenté cambiar de hecho varias veces el tipo de licencia de encabezado tal como sugería el mensaje , no sé si así se escribirá el concepto,pero en fin, con la herramienta PostMan efectivamente retornaba lo esperado sin dicho mensaje molesto. La cuestión es que lo acabé de resolver y era precisamente dicho comentario estaba sobre el index.php (ENRUTADOR A TRAVES DEL METODO GET [localhost/controlador/metodo/parametros]) justo en la parte superior de todo el código, lo quité y sencillamente todo volvio a la normalidad despues de 8 horas, 27 minutos *_*

Answer (score 3):

si bien es cierto que las cabeceras son importantes a la hora de publicar nuestro proyecto a algo más formal o simplemente distribuirlo como código libre ajustándonos a los parámetros legales exigidos por la industria, NO era precisamente la causa del problema,  en la medida que iba creando nuevos archivos PHP éstos creaban un código auto-comentado, la  cabecera correspondiente a la nueva configuración, es decir, tus datos personales como el correo, nombres completos etc etc... la cuestión es que uno de los archivos más importantes del proyecto, si es que no es el más importante, me refiero al famoso archivo "index.php" (NO HTML OJO - SOLO ES EL ENRUTADOR PARA GESTIONAR URL AMIGABLES) tenia precisamente el mensaje incomodo comentado en version HTML  simplemente lo suprimí y todo volvió a la normalidad. Les adjunto la evidencia de la solución para que nunca les pase algo tan incomodo:
 [image: código PHP del comentario que no había tenido en cuenta ELIMINAR!]
[image: código fuente de la pagina renderizada y devuelta por el servidor]

Finalmente hice una prueba realizando una petición tipo POST a través de AJAX y el retorno fue únicamente lo que yo esperaba!! mi JSON puro sin ningún comentario HTML incomodo que me robó 8.5 horas de trabajo, saludos a quienes les pueda interesar...